# Time it takes for an object to sink?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, water, drag, buoyancy

I am trying to determine how long it takes for an object to hit the bottom of the water. I've been looking at [Stoke's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_law), but can't quite figure out how to get to my answer.

Obviously, there are a lot of variables given, water conditions and which orientation the object travels in the water.

Details:

- Object volume: $(8 \times 12 \times 2) \ cm$
- Object weight: $260 \ g$
- Seawater
- Depth: $16 \ m$

Answer (score 2):

The answer is complicated and depends on a variety of different quantities. I can list a couple of forces that you may want to consider:

- Drag Force: When a solid object travels through a fluid, it will experience a drag force that resists its motion, given by the formula
  $$F_D = \frac{1}{2}C_D A \rho_f v^2$$
  where $C_D$ is the drag coefficient (you can look at a table for the drag coefficient of different objects), $A$ is the cross-sectional area, $\rho_f$ is the density of the fluid, and $v$ is the velocity of the object.

Stoke's law here is not valid because the object is not exactly a sphere. However, in high enough speeds, the viscosity of the fluid can matter more.

- Buoyant Force: Fluids will exert an upwards force on the object, given by the formula
  $$F_B = \rho_f g V$$
  where $\rho_f$ is the density of the fluid and $V$ is its volume.
- Weight: The natural downwards attraction of the body to Earth is given as $$F_W = mg.$$

You will then get a differential equation in the form of
$$F_{\text{net}} = m \frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}t} = F_W - F_D - F_B.$$
From here, you can solve the equation to get the velocity as a function of time, and accordingly how much time it will take for it to travel a certain distance.